# self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; does not work in pushed view

Tags: iphone, view, controllers

I want to draw something in `drawRect` of pushed view.
Also, I want to change back ground color of view.

I can change background color by `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];` in `viewDidLoad`, if view is main view.

I used that in `viewDidLoad` of pushed `view controller`, but it is still black.

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [MyViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationContoller pushViewController:myViewContoller animated:YES]; // I want to change background color of this view.
[myViewController release];
```

Comment: Oops. Actually, It worked. CGContextClearRect in drawRect caused it no effect. I deleted that line, it works.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `myViewController`'s background color before pushing it should work.

```
myViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
// push myViewController.
```

Or you can go to the `viewWillAppear` of that view and set the backgroundColor there.

Answer (score 3):

In Apple Swift, We can use:

> self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

Background will change to Green

Answer (score 0):

You actually should customize your view in `viewDidLoad` of your pushed view. Thats what it is made for.